How can call some vba's internal function in excel's cell?
In VBE window,vba can call worksheet function with application.worksheetfunction.fun_name.
The STRCONV function is a built-in function in Excel that is categorized as a String/Text Function. It can be used as a VBA function (VBA) in Excel's macro.

How can call some vba's internal function in excel's cell?

You can just set the value of the strconv function to a variable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function

You need to define an interface (wrapper) for this function in the standard VBA module:
Function StrConv(str As String, conversion As Integer, Optional LCID As Long)
    StrConv = VBA.StrConv(str, conversion, LCID)
End Function

As a conversion argument in Excel sheet you should use integer values instead of VBA constants, e.g. use 1 instead of vbUpperCase.
